# Installation Error 1935

Tags: installation, windows-installer

While installing my msi i get the follwing error

```
Error 1935. An error occurred during the installation of assembly component {98CB24AD-52FB-DB5F-A01F-C8B3B9A1E18E}. HRESULT: 0x800736B3. assembly interface: IAssemblyCacheItem, function: Commit, assembly name: Microsoft.VC80.CRT,type="win32",version="8.0.50727.42",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86"
```

I do carry Microsoft_VC80_CRT_x86.msm in my MSI. But the problem is that i do not see this issue in all machines. This is faced only on a 2012 Windows Virtual machine.

Can anyone please tell me why this error would normally come?

Comment: That is ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND.  You'll find an event for it in the Windows event log.  Chicken-and-egg problem, your installer needs to install the CRT *before* it tries to use it.  And yes, you won't see it all that often since it frequently is already installed on a machine.  Testing on a virgin machine is important.

Comment: I don't think that's the case here.  The error is coming from the commit phase of the installer.  MsiPublishAssemblies is trying to commit the DLL to the SXS and throwing an error.  Googling suggests this is an issue that sometimes occurs on corrupted windows installations.  Google the error code and you'll get suggestions to run sfc to scan the O/S or use the system readiness tool.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a corrupted windows O/S.  Otherwise it is correct to test on VM's configured with a variety of virgin operating systems that you want to support.  Additionally I highly advise to never use this merge module.  Instead using a bootstrapper/chainer (WiX Burn, InstallShield Setup Prereqs or Suite Installation ) to install the stand alone versions of the redist from Microsoft.   This helps draw a line in the sand between a Microsoft problem and a problem with your installer.  It also makes upgrade servicing easier.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message on windows 7 (32bit).
This was caused by a failure in windows update for my case.

After that, I cannot install any other program on the computer. I searched from internet and found suggestions made by Microsoft engineers: repair the system from Original Installation disc with "update to latest" choice unchecked.

However, I found another simple solution which also works for my case.

1． Click START>>  and type “regedit” to run register editor;

2． Find the following directory in register: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Control`;

3．  search by F3 for the key `RegistrySizeLimit` and double click the `DWORD`;

4． Change the key value into `ffffffff`(Hex) or decimal `4294967295`, then click OK;

5． restart the computer;

6． run `cmd.exe` with Administrator's privilege,  and type `SFC /SCANNOW` followed by Enter in command line; this scanning may take several minutes until the status is 100% and finishes;

Then the problem can be fixed!!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in my Win7x64 VM after I installed .NET Framework 4.5 required by my MSI. I had a fresh OS install with no Windows updates, plus VS2005 SP1. I ran this Microsoft FixIt: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976982/en-us, but it did not help until I restarted the VM. Once I restarted the VM, the error disappeared. I think all I needed was a restart, but I provide the above details in case it was the FixIt that actually fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

On a windows 2016 server, I solved the problem by resetting DCOM security to default

- launch dcomcnfg
- then set Default Authentication Level to Connect
- and Default Impersonation Level to Identify

[image]